# php mysql getting count WHERE BETWEEN AND

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, between

Hey i have a little problem when i'm trying to get count of rows from table, where `date` is `BETWEEN 2012-09-01 AND 2012-09-32`...

Could you please tell me where's the problem?

```
$month = date(m);
$year = date(Y);
$day_start = '01';
$day_end = '32';

$from = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day_start;
$till = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day_end;

$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `dreams` WHERE dream_state='dream' AND date BETWEEN $from AND $till");
$row1 = $result1->fetch_row();
$this_dream = $row1[0];
```

i've tryed to convert the string to time and from time to date like this:

```
$from = strtotime($from);
$from = date("Y-m-d",$from);

$till = strtotime($till);
$till = date("Y-m-d",$till);
```

but still doesn't work, so any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using greater than and less than operators instead of between to see if there's a difference in the result?

Comment: `2012-09-32` .. there are 32 days in September?

Comment: @AJ. Yes, i've tryed using >= <=, same thing!

Comment: dates in query must be escaped! "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `dreams` WHERE dream_state='dream' AND date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$till'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `date` column needs to be some kind of date datatype, like `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Second, you need to use valid dates for comparison. September 32 is no good. When MySQL tries to interpret that date it gets NULL.  All comparisons between real values and NULLs come up false. So, you get an empty result set.

Third, `BETWEEN` is terrible for date comparison ; it often fouls up the end -- the last day -- of the range.

I suggest you use a query like this.  Notice that the second `date` comparison to is the day *after* the end of the range you want.

```
$month = date(m);
$year = date(Y);
$day_start = '01';
$from = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day_start;

$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) 
                             FROM `dreams`
                            WHERE dream_state='dream' 
                              AND date >= '$from'
                              AND date < '$from' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
$row1 = $result1->fetch_row();
$this_dream = $row1[0];
```

Comment: All comparisons between real values and NULLs come up **`UNKNOWN`**, not false.

Answer (score 0):

You include dashes in your dates but don't quote them as strings in the SQL. There are no date literals in SQL, so you have to represent dates as strings upon entry. Simply enclose them in single quotes to represent SQL value strings.

```php
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `dreams` WHERE dream_state='dream'
                           AND date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$till'");
```

You also have an invalid date, as no month has 32 days. Computing the last day of each month seems a bit of an overkill here, so you're probably better off describing the first day of the next month, and using `<` to exclude it from the range.

*A previous version of this answer suggested using numbers to describe dates instead of strings. While this works, it might be quite bad for performance, as @ypercube pointed out in a comment below.*

Comment: This is very bad advice. If you want to compare dates, compare dates. Don't convert them to other types first. You lose any chance of indexes used this way.

Comment: @hypercube, there are no date literals, so you either have to enter strings or numbers. But a [quick test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5b12/1) shows that you're right: converting to numbers requires forcing the date column to number as well (e.g. `+0`), and does break use of the index. Will edit my answer.

Comment: The query (that compares a date column with a number literal) may be working and even using the index. My comment was just a general one that it's better not to convert columns or use code that may lead to column conversions in queries. (Oh and your quick test may be failing due to Sep-31 date :)

Comment: It doesn't fail to yield desired results (slightly strange, now that I [think](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5b12/10) about it), but failed to use the index.

Comment: Try this one [sql-fiddle-Aug](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5b12/16) (check the execution plans). And then the [sql-fiddle-Sep-not-existing-pdate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5b12/17) (and again execution plans and **different** results)

Comment: Looks like for a proper valid date, the index is never used, not even when comparing strings. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Index not used, probably due to the tiny tables.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, use **placeholders**. Putting quotation marks in your query to try and delimit inserted variables is usually a sign you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: @tadman, I agree with you, but not having used PHP myself in a long time, I didn't find the placeholder syntax at first glance. So I decided to stay as close to the original code as possible. Do you want to create your own answer using that syntax?

Comment: Same idea but with `?` instead of `'$from'`, a prepared statement, and a later call to bind parameters. Placeholders are essential, not optional.